# silex php framework mix with grunt

Tags: php, html, gruntjs, silex

```
I have this configurations in grunt

/**
 * Generated on 2013-07-31 using generator-angular 0.3.0
 * To generate a separate angular template just install grunt grunt cli
 * @Author: Frank Marcelo
 */
'use strict';

module.exports = function (grunt) {
  require('matchdep').filterDev('grunt-*').forEach(grunt.loadNpmTasks);

  // configurable paths
  var yeomanConfig = {
    app:  '../app/views/development',
    appImages: '../app/img',
    dist: '../app/views/production',
    less: 'css/less',
    binless: '../bin/less',
    css: 'css',
    js: 'js',
    images: 'img',
    timestamp: (new Date()).getTime().toString(),
    randomPort:  Math.floor((Math.random() * 10000) + 1)
  };

  try {
    yeomanConfig.app = require('./bower.json').appPath || yeomanConfig.app;
  } catch (e) {}

  grunt.initConfig({
    yeoman: yeomanConfig,
    jshint: {
      options: { jshintrc: '.jshintrc', reporter: require('jshint-stylish')},
      all: [
        'Gruntfile',
        'js/{,*/}*.js'
      ]
    },
    imagemin: {
      dist: {
        options: {
          optimizationLevel: 7
        },
        files: [{
          expand: false,
          cwd: '<%= yeoman.images %>/',
          src: '**/*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif}',
          dest: '<%= yeoman.images %>/dist/'
        }]
      }
    },
    cssmin: {
      dist: {
        options: { keepSpecialComments: 0},
        files: {
          '<%= yeoman.css %>/ie8.css': ['<%= yeoman.less %>/ie8.less'],
          '<%= yeoman.css %>/cyberu.css': ['<%= yeoman.less %>/cyberu.less'],
          '<%= yeoman.css %>/print.css': ['<%= yeoman.less %>/print.less'],
          '<%= yeoman.css %>/main.css': ['<%= yeoman.css %>/main.css']
        }
      }
    },
    htmlcompressor: {
      dist: {
        files: {
          '<%= yeoman.dist %>/index.html.twig': '<%= yeoman.dist %>/index.html.twig',
          '<%= yeoman.dist %>/print.lesson.html.twig': '<%= yeoman.dist %>/print.lesson.html.twig',
          '<%= yeoman.dist %>/404.html.twig': '<%= yeoman.dist %>/404.html.twig',
          '<%= yeoman.dist %>/elements/base_headers.html.twig': '<%= yeoman.dist %>/elements/base_headers.html.twig',
          '<%= yeoman.dist %>/elements/analytics.html.twig': '<%= yeoman.dist %>/elements/analytics.html.twig'
        },
        options: {
          type: 'html',
          preserveServerScript: true,
          compressJs: true,
          compressCss: true
        }
      }
    },
    clean: {
      dist: {
        options: {
          force: true
        },
        src: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/*', '<%= yeoman.images %>/*']
      }
    },
    concurrent: {
      dist: [
        'usemin'
      ],
      options: {
        logConcurrentOutput: true
      }
    },
    copy: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/',
          src: ['**'],
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/'
        }, {
          expand: true,
          cwd: '<%= yeoman.appImages %>/',
          src: ['**'],
          dest: '<%= yeoman.images %>/'
        }]
      }
    },

    less: {
      development: {
        options: {
          paths: ['<%= yeoman.binless %>']
        },
        files: {
          '<%= yeoman.css %>/main.css': "<%= yeoman.binless %>/main.less"
        }
      }
    },
    ngmin: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '<%= yeoman.js %>',
          src: ['modules.js'],
          dest: '<%= yeoman.js %>'
        }]
      }
    },
    uglify: {
      dist: {
        options: {
          beautify: true
        },
        files: {
          '<%= yeoman.js %>/vendor/components.js': ['<%= yeoman.js %>/vendor/components.js']
        }
      }
    },
    useminPrepare: {
      html: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/index.html.twig', '<%= yeoman.app %>/elements/base_headers.html.twig', '<%= yeoman.app %>/print.lesson.html.twig'],
      options: {
        dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
      }
    },
    usemin: {
      html: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/{,*/}*.twig'],
      css: ['<%= yeoman.css %>/{,*/}*.css'],
      options: {
        assetsDirs: ['<%= yeoman.images %>'],
        patterns: {
          js: [
            [/(img\/.*?\.(?:gif|jpeg|jpg|png|webp))/gm, 'Update the JS to reference our revved images']
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    replace: {
      distBuildTime: {
        options: {
          variables: {
            'build-time': '<%= yeoman.timestamp %>'
          },
          prefix: '@@'
        },
        expand: true,
        cwd: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
        src: ['**/{,*/}*.twig'],
        dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
      }
    },
    rev: {
      dist: {
        files: {
          src: [
            '<%= yeoman.images %>/{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif}'
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    watch: {
      all: {
        files: ['Gruntfile.js', 'js/app/**/*', 'css/**/*', 'vendor/**/*', 'img/**/*', 'src/**/*'],
        tasks: ['default'],
        options: {
          livereload: true,
          nospawn: true,
          interrupt: true,
          debounceDelay: 250,
          dateFormat: function (time) {
            grunt.log.writeln('The watch finished in ' + time + 'ms at' + (new Date()).toString());
            grunt.log.writeln('Waiting for more changes...');
          }
        }
      }
    },
    reload: {
      port: '<%= yeoman.randomPort %>',
      liveReload: {},
      proxy: {
        host: 'localhost',
        port: 8282
      }
    }
  });

  grunt.registerTask('imageOptim', ['imagemin']);//optimise image
  grunt.registerTask('revision', ['rev', 'usemin']);//versioning
  grunt.registerTask('jslint', ['jshint']);//js hint and code coverage
  grunt.registerTask('css', ['cssmin', 'revision']);//css minify
  grunt.registerTask('default', [
    'clean:dist',
    'copy',
    'less',
    //'imagemin',
    'cssmin',
    'replace',
    'useminPrepare',
    'concat',
    'uglify',
    'rev',
    'usemin',
    'htmlcompressor',
    'reload'
  ]);


};
```

any way to use grunt revisions inside a twig template? because i cannot produce a proper deployed version of artefacts. Anyone has encountered my issues with grunt with silex symfony microframework?

Ive been digging with this issue for few days as maybe i can get some help

Comment: how do you reference your images in twig? just with a plain link as src or via assetic?